# Prevent map loading before quorum is reached when a client is already connected and fetched a map in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to prevent map loading mechanism from starting before a quorum of clusters is reached. I used **hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size** property and it works fine unless there was a client that was already connected and already has fetched a given map.

What I expected was that a client will be unable to perform any actions on a map as long as the quorum isn't reached.

What I observe is: if there is no client already connected and I restart the cluster, it awaits for the quorum and the maps are unavailable (that's great).
If there is a client already connected AND it fetches the map and I then restart the cluster (stop it completely and then start a node after node manually), the client somehow instructs the cluster to load a map and it indeed is loaded and only then the cluster awaits for the quorum. Is there a way of preventing this from happening?

Edit: It turns out that the map is loaded even if there wasn't a client before and simply a fresh client connects and requests a map. It looks like the cluster is open for business for clients before it reaches it's quorum.

Answer (score 0):

Is your client connection configured for reconnect?
i.e. connection-strategy async-start="false" reconnect-mode="ON"

I can indeed reproduce this and am not sure whether this is intended behavior or not.  I have posed this question on github.  At any rate, would configuring the map's quorum size suffice?  This map configuration will actually block until quorum size is met.

```
    <map name="my-test-map">
        <quorum-ref>quorumRuleWithTwoNodes</quorum-ref>
    </map>

    <quorum name="quorumRuleWithTwoNodes" enabled="true">
        <quorum-size>2</quorum-size>
    </quorum>
```

Comment: I tried using explicit quorum before, but I was getting an exception instead of the map being blocked.